Validation of same DTO in different situations using jakarta.validation in Spring Boot
Through my work I've always had dilema about proper way to validate DTOs in Spring Boot. I am consantly facing this situation for example:
I have for example OrganizationDTO where attributes like name and code are must and annotated with @NotBlank when doing creation of Organization (POST method in controller).
But when doing creation for example of Product using ProductDTO, which has attribute OrganizationDTO then only UUID inside of OrganizationDTO is must.
Through my career I handled this using Validation Groups, but want I don't like is that I ended up using marker interface for almost every entity which is being created and validated in controller.

Write better DTOs specific for that usecase and not re-use. Or use validation groups as you already do.
